# Error when searching for Participants

Tags: civievent, participants, 5.0

I got the following fatal error in the "Find Participants" page (Events > Find Participants), when I click on the Search button :

[image]

My website is using WordPress version 4.9.5 with PHP 7.0 and MySQL 5.7.
This problem seems to occur in the 5.0.0 , 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 versions of CiviCRM. I've never seen this problem before version 5.0.0.

The SQL code in the error log :

```
SELECT

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as contact_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contact_a.contact_type) as `contact_type`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contact_a.contact_sub_type) as `contact_sub_type`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contact_a.sort_name) as `sort_name`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contact_a.display_name) as `display_name`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_event.id) as event_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_event.title) as event_title, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_event.start_date) as event_start_date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_event.end_date) as event_end_date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_event.default_role_id) as `default_role_id`, 
civicrm_participant.id as participant_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.fee_level) as participant_fee_level, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.fee_amount) as participant_fee_amount, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.fee_currency) as participant_fee_currency, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT event_type.label) as event_type, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.status_id) as participant_status_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT participant_status.label) as participant_status, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.role_id) as participant_role_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.role_id) as participant_role, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.register_date) as participant_register_date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.source) as participant_source, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_note.note) as participant_note, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.is_pay_later) as participant_is_pay_later, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.is_test) as participant_is_test, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.registered_by_id) as participant_registered_by_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT discount_name.title) as participant_discount_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.campaign_id) as participant_campaign_id   

FROM

civicrm_contact contact_a 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant 
        ON civicrm_participant.contact_id = contact_a.id  
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_event 
        ON civicrm_participant.event_id = civicrm_event.id  
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_event_type 
        ON (option_group_event_type.name = 'event_type') 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value event_type 
        ON (civicrm_event.event_type_id = event_type.value 
            AND option_group_event_type.id = event_type.option_group_id )  
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_discount discount 
        ON ( civicrm_participant.discount_id = discount.id ) 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group discount_name 
        ON ( discount_name.id = discount.price_set_id )  
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_note 
        ON ( civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_participant' 
            AND civicrm_participant.id = civicrm_note.entity_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_participant_role 
        ON (option_group_participant_role.name = 'participant_role') 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value participant_role 
        ON ((civicrm_participant.role_id = participant_role.value 
            OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(role_id,'', 1) = participant_role.value)
            AND option_group_participant_role.id = participant_role.option_group_id )  
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_participant_status_type participant_status 
        ON (civicrm_participant.status_id = participant_status.id)  

WHERE       ( civicrm_participant.is_test = 0 )  
  AND       (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   

GROUP BY    civicrm_participant.id,  
            participant_register_date desc,  
            contact_a.id  

ORDER BY    `participant_register_date` desc, 
            `contact_a`.`id`  

LIMIT 0, 50
```

The error :

```
[nativecode=1056 ** Can't group on 'participant_register_date']
```

I tested this code in phpmyadmin , and it works when I replace `participant_register_date` in the `GROUP BY` by `civicrm_participant.register_date` but I don't know which file I need to change in civicrm to do the fix...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kevin,

This is a core bug and is fixed under https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11996/files

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: When will this go into the official releases? I get this on 5.1.2 for "Events Dashboard".

Comment: Unfortunately there is back and forth discussion on the implementation model, i think it should be out in 5.2 not sure though